# Android smooth translation animation like android navigation drawer

Tags: android, xml, animation

I have a linearlayout which I want to slide in from right to left on the press of a button. I want to achieve animation like that of usual navigation drawer, smooth and swift.

I have used following xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="400"
android:fromXDelta="-100%"
android:toXDelta="0%"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
/>
```

But the animation is not smooth and more jumpy to say. Can anyone guide, what would be the basics if I have to achieve animation like that of navigation drawer.

Comment: try with linear interpolator...

Comment: tried it with linear interpolator as well upon your advice but still its jumpy

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the duration. i.e

```
 android:duration="800"
```